# Sorting files to folders whith Vite build

Tags: reactjs, vite

When building application with Vite, I need to sort the files inside the dist/assets folder into /js, /css, /img folders.

vite.config.ts

```
Import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
        outDir: '../build',
        assetsDir: 'static'
    }
})
```

I didn't find an option to sort by file type.